# British visa validity

Tags: visas

I am a Pakistan national. My UK visa is valid till 25 Feb 2015. I am traveling to UK on 18Feb 2015. Can I stay in UK after 25 Feb 2015 or 25 Feb 2015 is last date to stay in UK.

Comment: Why this confusion ? Visa ends on 25/02 means pack your bags and off you go, there is no ambiguity in that. And considering many people from Indian subcontinent tend to overstay you will most probably be grilled on your arrival. You will be deemed an overstayer and if you exceed 28 days of overstay you will be banned for 10 years for applying for an UK visa. And this information will be shared across EU countries and may make other countries will refuse you visa, on your old record.

Answer (score 2):

Being allowed to stay within the country after the expiry of the visa is extremely uncommon and probably the US are the only country that allows this (under certain circumstances and for certain visa types, such as student visa).

If your visa is valid until the 25th of February 2015, then this is the last day that you may be in the country, unless 
(1) you have another UK visa for after that day, or
(2) your cleared passport control on an international airport at the 25th while your flight is (early) on the 26th.
In both cases, there may be some non-trivial process that your would need to follow, though.

Note that when clearing immigration on the 18th, the immigration officer may want to see a proof of booked onward travel for leaving the country before or on the 25th. This is actually quite likely to happen if your enter the UK a few days before your visa expires. So you are strongly advised to be prepared for this case.